# React Native, Requeting Read SMS Permission not work

Tags: react-native

I want to read phone sms using expo react-native, I'm sending request to read sms permission and nothing is happening.

When I click the button it's not opening the alert modal

here is my code:

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import '@babel/helper-skip-transparent-expression-wrappers'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React,{useState,useEffect,useRef} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
import RootStackScreen from './android/screens/RootStackScreen'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Alert, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  async function requestSmsPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_SMS,
      {
        title: 'My App SMS Permission',
        message:
          'My App needs access to your SMS messages ' +
          'so you can read them in the app.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('You can read SMS messages');
    } else {
      console.log('SMS permission denied');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

  return (
     <>
     <View style={{marginTop: 200}}></View>
      <Button
      title="Request SMS Permission"
      onPress={requestSmsPermission}
      style={{marginTop: 400}}
    />
     </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I want the codes to ask user permission to read sms using expo, react-native